# Get ZXing Reader to decode a bitmap

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I haven't yet been able to decode a QR code with ZXing.  I'm using a BUG from buglabs.net but the problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the hardware, but rather the format of the image.

This is what I have so far:

```
try {
    LuminanceSource source = new AWTImageLuminanceSource(bimage);
    bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));
    Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
    hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
    Result result = reader.decode(bitmap, hints) ;
    System.out.println("result is:" + result.getText());
    } catch (ReaderException re) {
            System.out.println("I can't find a barcode here");
    }
```

The code breaks at reader.decode(bitmap, hints).  I'm getting a NullPointerException with the following trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at qrcoder.QRCoder.shoot(QRCoder.java:152) // this is the camera shoot function
    at qrcoder.QRCoder.buttonEvent(QRCoder.java:89) // press button
    at com.buglabs.bug.input.pub.InputEventProvider.run(InputEventProvider.java:90)
```

Not sure what the InputEventProvider is trying to tell me.

Thanks so much,
Sara

Not sure how, but Reader was never getting written to.  Finally works by substituting the Reader's own source code back into the function, using Decoder directly instead.

```
private void shoot() throws IOException, NotFoundException, FormatException,     ChecksumException {
    // take the picture
    Hashtable hints = null;
    DecoderResult decoderResult;
    cameraLED.setLEDFlash(true);
    camera.grabPreview(buf);
    camera.grabPreview(buf);
    cameraLED.setLEDFlash(false);
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(camera.grabFull());
    BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
    LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bImageFromConvert);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    ResultPoint[] points;

      final Decoder decoder = new Decoder();
      DetectorResult detectorResult = new Detector(bitmap.getBlackMatrix()).detect(hints);
      decoderResult = decoder.decode(detectorResult.getBits(), hints);
      points = detectorResult.getPoints();
      Result result = new Result(decoderResult.getText(), decoderResult.getRawBytes(), points, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

    if (result.getText() != null){
        System.out.println("result is:" + result.getText());
        }           
        else {System.out.println("bitmap is null");}     


    ic.repaint();
}
```

This works for now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is sample code for BUG in the project, contributed by the BUG guys. See `bug/`. It's quite old though.

`QRCoder` is your class, no? so I don't know if this is a problem with BUG or the library.

Comment: The library is working fine - I got it directly from the Bug Labs folks.  I'm not using the camera at the moment, I'm importing an image directly into the function.

Comment: Finally got it to work by replacing Reader with its own source code.  Not sure how, but the reader was never getting written.